# How to check, In a Get method the particular data is matching or not in a restsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

Guy's I'm new to RestSharp for doing automation on API. 
How to know the particular data is existed in a Get method. In my API, 3 objects are existed. Those are pagination, data & info. 
At now i want to check, firstname value is matching or not in a 'data' object.

I'm used a JsonDeserializer concept. But I'm unable to move the 'data' object.

```
var client = new RestClient("https://ecovon.com/search?keyword=marketing&page=1");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

//Header values.
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

//Execute script
IRestResponse restResponse = client.Execute(request);
var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();
var output = deserialize.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(restResponse);

var result = output["firstname"];
Assert.AreEqual(result, "Matt", "Name not matched.");
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you don't.

When you unit test APIs you have a number of options.

1. you could add some test data and then work with that, however it gets tricky when multiple people trigger the automated tests and then data gets changed so I am not a big fan of this approach.
2. before you test anything, first you create the data you need and assert against that. When you're done you simply delete the data you created so it doesn't pollute the existing system under test.

Imagine this scenario:

you have a user, first name is **Frank** and second name is **Johnson**. You also need a unique email address to be able to create it.

you want to test a method which returns the full name **Frank Johnson**.

You could use a guid as username in the format guid@something.com where you specify the GUID yourself. it will be unique so that part is covered. You setup the rest of the data. This is done using an endpoint of the API.

Once the user is created, then you start calling the endpoint you actually want to test using something you know to identify the correct user, maybe their email, an id, whatever you have.

You do the assert, verify everything is correct and finally you use another endpoint to delete all this data you've just created. This could even be an endpoint you don't expose in production for example, or you secure it so it can't be used by anyone else.

So, your endpoint test now involves calling 3 endpoints:

- create test data
- call the endpoint under test and do the asserts
- delete the test data

it is a bit more work but worth it and it gives you the certainty that everything works as it should.

you follow this method for anything else you want to test, so in your case create what you need, according to your test scenario, you will know how much data you should get and what it should look like and you're done.

Comment: Hi @andrei,Could you please provide a live example for better understanding.
Along with you had any framework for API Automation? please share me.